# elixir ecto - changeset differences between create and update

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have this `Ecto.Schema` with the `changeset` like below:

```
  def changeset(current_case, attrs) do
    current_case
    |> cast(attrs, [:case_id, :latitude, :longitude, :user_id])
    |> cast_coordinates() 
    end

    def cast_coordinates(changeset) do
    lat = get_change(changeset, :latitude)
    lng = get_change(changeset, :longitude)
    geo = %Geo.Point{coordinates: {lng, lat}, srid: 4326}
    changeset |> put_change(:coordinates, geo)
    end
```

Basically, it is a simple table taking in `case_id`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `user_id`.

Occassionally, user will update their location but sometimes, they only update the `case_id` without update location.

`cast_coordinates` will take `latitude` and `longitude` to convert it into `geo point` then input into `changeset`.

when `create/1`, I won't have issue, because `changes` in `changeset` will have all the data.

but when `update/2`, I will get `argument error` if I only want to update:

1. `latitude` only, because `longitude` in `changes` will be `nil`.
2. `longitude` only, because `latitude` in `changes` will be `nil`.
3. no location update, because both of it will be `nil`.
4. I can't even forcefully inject `latitude` or `longitude` from `current_case`, changeset will treat them as no changes, thus the value will be `nil`.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [get_field/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#get_field/3) instead of [get_change/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#get_change/3).

`get_change/3` only fetches changes, so if `attrs` doesn't include latitude or longitude, it will return `nil`.

`get_field/3` fetches from the changes *or* from the data. When updating, your data from `current_case` should contain the current latitude and longitude values, which will be returned instead of `nil`.